# Unable to iterate Java List in Scala

Tags: java, scala, twitter4j

I'm using the Java Twitter4J library in a Scala project.

I'm calling the method

```
twitter.getFriendsStatuses()
```

This method returns a list of twitter4j.User objects containing statuses.

I try to iterate over them and it goes in an infinite loop over the first element:

```
val users:List[User] = twitter.getFriendsStatuses(userId, paging.getSinceId())
while( users.iterator.hasNext() ) {
  println(users.iterator.next().getStatus())
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I guess `users.iterator` produces the new iterator each time it's evaluated. Try this:

```
val it = users.iterator
while(it.hasNext() ) {
   println(it.next().getStatus())
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why didn't I think of that! :-)

Answer (score 18):

If you use Scala 2.8, you could use JavaConversion to convert Java collection to Scala collection automatically.

Ex.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

// Java Collection
val arrayList = new java.util.ArrayList[Int]
arrayList.add(2)
arrayList.add(3)
arrayList.add(4)

// It will implicitly covert to Scala collection, 
// so you could use map/foreach...etc.
arrayList.map(_ * 2).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 8):

What's wrong with just

```
users.foreach(user => println(user.getStatus()))
```

or even

```
users.map(_.getStatus()).foreach(println _)
```

or, if you're worried about traversing the collection twice

```
users.view.map(_.getStatus()).foreach(println _)
```

IOW: Why do you want to manage the iteration yourself (and possibly make mistakes), when you can just let someone else do the work for you?

Comment: Nothing's wrong. I've just begun learning Scala. Thanks for the examples! PS: These are Java Lists, will check if your examples work.

Comment: Nope, sorry. Twitter4J returns me a java.util.List and .foreach, .map, .view.map don't work out of the box. Is there some neat way to convert these into Scala Lists and make use of .foreach, .map and .view's?

Comment: @Srirangan: `import collection.JavaConversions._` and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer scalaj-collection to scala.collection.JavaConversions. This makes the conversions explicit:

```
import scalaj.collection.Implicits._

val arrayList = new java.util.ArrayList[Int]
arrayList.add(2)
arrayList.add(3)
arrayList.add(4)

arrayList.asScala.map(_ * 2).foreach(println)
```

Available here: https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-collection

Comment: I didn't know about scalaj-collection, but in Scala 2.8, at least, `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._` will give you explicit `.asScala`conversions if you want them.

Comment: Yeah, I'd heard about that but haven't had the time to really look into the implementation of JavaConverters. scalaj-collection is pretty clean, so I've kind of stuck to that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using

`scala.collection.JavaConverters._`

and simply add `.asScala` to every object you wish to iterate